# Java endpoint - perl consumer web service

Tags: java, web-services, perl

I've problem with calling java endpoint (code below) from perl client (activePerl 5.16).
  Those code snippets are from book Java Web Services Up And Running

```
package ch01.ts;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style=Style.RPC)
public interface TimeServer {

    @WebMethod
    String getTimeAsString();

    @WebMethod
    long getTimeAsElapsed();
}
```

---

```
package ch01.ts;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface="ch01.ts.TimeServer")
public class TimeServerImpl implements TimeServer {

    public String getTimeAsString() {
        return new Date().toString();
    }

    public long getTimeAsElapsed() {
        return new Date().getTime();
    }
}
```

---

```
package ch01.ts;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class TimeServerPublisher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Endpoint.publish("http://127.0.0.1:9876/ts", new TimeServerImpl());
    }
}
```

---

And the perl consumer:

```
use SOAP::Lite;

my $url = 'http://127.0.0.1:9876/ts?wsdl';
my $service = SOAP::Lite->service($url);

print "\nCurrent time is: ",$service->getTimeAsString();
print "\nElapsed miliseconds from the epoch: ", $service->getTimeAsElapsed();
```

When I'm calling the web service I'm having this stack trace:

```
maj 04, 2013 10:21:40 AM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit    handle
SEVERE: Couldn't create SOAP message. Expecting Envelope in namespace     http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/, but got http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.protocol.soap.VersionMismatchException: Couldn't create SOAP   message. Expecting Envelope in namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/, but got   http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(Unknown Source)
```

I think that the soap version is the problem, above example is from 1.1, when I've change the client code to

```
my $service = SOAP::Lite->service($url)->soapversion('1.2');
```

then different error is throw

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 Supported ones are: [text/xml]
```

I need help with either dealing with envelope problem or content-type. I will be grateful for any directions, code and anything else that could help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure of Perl->Soap API, But for first case where client version is 1.1 may be you need to mention namespace also somewhere.

May be like

```
server->setNamespace() //or
SOAP::Lite->service($url,"<namespace>"); //please search for perl web service client         examples
```

And for second case(1.2) service is expecting text and your api sends soap encoding or something.

Refer http://www.herongyang.com/Web-Services/Perl-SOAP-1-2-Unsupported-Media-Type-application-soap.html

This may be helpful

```
  my $client = SOAP::Lite->new()
  ->soapversion('1.2')
  ->envprefix('soap12')
  ->default_ns('http://xmlme.com/WebServices')
  ->on_action( sub {join '/', @_} )
  ->readable(true)
  ->proxy('http://www.xmlme.com/WSShakespeare.asmx');
```

and

http://www.herongyang.com/Web-Services/Perl-SOAP-1-2-Request-Differences-SOAP-1-1-and-1-2.html

Hope it helps